# Python advance trick for grabbing data from dictionary

Tags: python

```
myDict = \
    {
        "R1": [10, 20],
        "R2": [20, 30],
        "K2": [20, 30],
        "N2": [20, 30],
        "N1": [20, 30],
     }
```

suppose I have this dictionary in python.

I want:

```
x, y = enumerate(myDict["R1"])
#doing some job over data
#at here x will be 10 and y will 20
x, y = enumerate(myDict["R2"])
#doing some job over data
```

This is just a small dict.  But I have so many data in it. So instead of writing for R1,R2,R3,....
is there any way like?

```
for x,y someCodeForR1toRn:
#doing some job over data
```

Comment: please clarify what you want

Comment: Please clarify what the range of keys you have. Is it just `"R1", "R2", "R3"`, or is it *much more*, eg: `"R1", "R2" ......, "R84756385", ... `?

Comment: the value of R1 if 10,20 which get assign to x and y. There are so many Rs. Like R1,R2,R3,R4,.... So instead of writing `x, y = enumerate(myDict["R1"])` for all is there any short way

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Please explain: the first time the loop runs, exactly what should the value of `x` be? Exactly what should the value of `y` be? What is the rule that tells you what those values are? Then, the same thing the second time through the loop, and so on. I can't understand the pattern you are trying to describe.

Comment: range does not matter I can type it as `x,y = emurate(someCode) in ["R1","R2","R3","Rn"]`

Comment: I'm not sure what you think `enumerate` actually does or how it works, but it doesn't seem to make sense for what you're describing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an outer loop, that loops over the arrays and a condition to use only `R*`

```
for key, value in myDict.items():
    if not key.startswith("R"):
        continue
    print("Doing stuff for", key)
    for x, y in enumerate(value):
        print(x, y)
```

Comment: but the dictionary contain other data also like "K1","N1","N2","B1". I don't want that

Comment: Your answer is correct but need to change last second line to `x,y = value[0],value[1]`. Otherwise for loop run for twice

Comment: @stackaayush i'd just use enumerate as you mentionned in your question, that is totally different of `x,y = value[0],value[1]` so I don't know what you want

Answer (score 1):

Just loop over the dict items:

```
myDict = {"R1": [10, 20],"R2": [150, 250],"N2": [150, 250]}

def key_is_interesting(k):
    return k[0] == 'R'

for k,v in myDict.items():
    if key_is_interesting(k):
        print(f'Doing some work with {k} and {v}')
```

Comment: but the dictionary contain other data also like "K1","N1","N2","B1". I don't want that

Comment: @stackaayush - what are the keys that you want to work with? Only those that start with R?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for key, (x, y) in myDict.items():
    print(f'The key {key} has values x={x} and y={y}')
```

Comment: but the dictionary contain other data also like "K1","N1","N2","B1". I don't want that

Comment: What is the rule that tells you which parts you want?

Comment: key start with R

Comment: So, inside the loop, you can check if the `key` starts with R, and `continue` otherwise.